# How do I quickly scan my DB and update it only if an external source has changed?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a table `Links` of links, that was initially populated using Nokogiri.

I just crawled a site, got all the links in the site and dumped them into a table.

I don't expect some of them to change too often - maybe once per month. Some will never change. But basically I want to run my method to that will then execute Nokogiri and come back with a list of links.

I want to check each of the links against my database and only add a new record when a link is found that is not in the db.

How do I go about doing that in the most efficient way possible?

Assume I have an array `new_links` of the newest links that I got from Nokogiri.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert only the new links

```
#Remove found links from new_links array and insert them into DB
links_to_insert = new_links - Link.where(['url IN (?)', new_links]) 
links_to_insert.each { |link| Link.create!(link) }
```

Elegant ?